# Where to keep static fixtures (files) in Java project?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2

I'm testing a number of classes which manipulate files on disc. I created a number of "mocked" files which I will pass to these classes. The question is where in my directory tree I should save them? I'm using Maven.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like they should be in `src/main/resources`, if you need them at runtime, or `src/test/resources` if they're merely inputs to tests.

This is assuming that they're otherwise opaque data files with no special properties that Maven can do anything interesting with (for example, XSD schemas/SQL/scripting language files).